# c# - can one pass parameters by value or as an object to function w/o overloading it

Tags: c#

In c# is there a way to create (or call) a function that accepts discreet parameters or an object of those parameters with out overloading it?

like:

```
function void foo(string a, string b, int c)
{
...
}

class boo{
  public string x {get;set;}
  public string y {get;set;}
  public int z {get;set;}
}
```

and then one could call it either way:

```
foo("asdf", "asdf", 1);

//or:

var zz = new boo(){x="asdf", y="asdf", z=1};
foo(zz);
```

I feel like we could do this in ColdFusion, which was precompiled I believe, by passing structs into functions... it was super handy for logging purposes (you could log the input by serializing the struct instead of creating a string with all the parameters values for logging... )

Comment: No, there is no construct in C# to do this. you'd have to overload it and replace the parameters with a parameter class.

Comment: Actually you _could_ do this (the call) by using the [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword like `foo (params object[] arguments)` but you neither can access the data in it (in a clear way without casting) nor _should_ you do that. Why would you build something that is not specific? I would try to rethink what you are trying to achieve here ;-)

Comment: If your language uses a calling convention where it always in-fact packages up the parameters into an object you can see how this would be cheap to support. But in a language like C# where they try to allow `ref` and the like to reduce calling overheads, not so easy.

Comment: @MarkusSafar No, that would just needlessly create an array to contain a single object; it would not achieve what OP is asking for.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The OP has asked if it is possible to call a function like this, I would say it is possible in that way. But it is definitly not clean code and I would never go for that nor accept it in that way ;-)

Comment: @MarkusSafar OP wants to pass a single object, and infer the arguments from it's properties. `params` will just wrap that object in an array.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I don't see any statement about "infer the arguments". I do know what `params` does and I explicitly mentioned, that it is neither clean nor the way to go but it would work (if casted properly).

Comment: @MarkusSafar Ah OK I understand what your saying; if there is 1 item then cast that to a `Bar` and use it's properties, or else cast the 3 items. Obviously extremely brittle as you mentioned.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Exactly but very, very ugly. Although I've seen stuff like that :D

Comment: Why would I want this - 
1) Partially to know if I can... 
2) Overriding functions can get messy... default and optional parameters can make functions messy...
3) I had 1 use case where I wanted to store all the inputs to a function and hardcoding them in a logging call means someone will eventually change the method signature and won't update the logger call and we won't be logging all the incoming data. But if all the data was in an object and the object was 'spread' in the function and then we serialized the object for logging, then that reduces the risk of this happening.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. C# being strongly typed means each function needs to know what specific types the arguments are. Is there a reason that you don't want to overload?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on why you don't want to use an override.

If the reason is that the function is in a library that you can't change, then the answer is yes, actually! You can create a lambda function that calls the original function by parsing the values from the object, and then pass that lambda to wherever it needs to go.

But if you don't want to write the override because it is too verbose for it's doing (and you would prefer to use something like the spread operator from JS), then you are out of luck, the lambda is just as verbose as the override.

Answer (score -1):

## Solution without override

You can try using combination of [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params), [selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) and [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) concepts assuming that:

- basic types such numbers, chars or strings are processed as is,
- all properties are extracted from classes and their values are processed by one of two ways (see below for details).

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foo("qwerty", "asdf", 1);
        var zz = new boo() { x = "abc", y = "xyz", z = 2 };
        foo(zz);
    }

    class boo
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
    }

    static void foo(params object[] values)
    {
        foreach (object value in values)
        {
            Type type = value.GetType();
            if (type.IsPrimitive // For char, int, double, etc.
                || type == typeof(string)) // It's crutch for string because 
                                           // string is not primitive type, 
                                           // but should be handled here. 
                                           // Who can improve it?
            {
                // Place here instructions like foo(string a, string b, int c)
                Console.WriteLine(value + " \thas been handled");
            }
            // ... Place here additional checks.
            else // For types that have properties (like your class boo).
            {
                try 
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
                    {
                        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(value, index: null);
                        /* W A R N I N G ! ! !                              */
                        /* Choose and leave ONLY one of 2 ways as necessary */

                        /*       Fisrt way      */
                        // Place here instructions like foo(zz)
                        Console.WriteLine(propertyValue + "\thas been handled");

                        /*        - or -        */

                        /*      Second way      */
                        // Just pass it recursively:
                        foo(propertyValue);
                        // This method is better in that it processes 
                        // the entire tree of nested properties.
                    }
                }   
                catch
                {
                    // On error there is nothing to do.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console output for this example looks like this:

```
qwerty  has been handled
asdf    has been handled
1       has been handled
abc     has been handled
xyz     has been handled
2       has been handled
```

Of course, this example is not for all occasions, but for your purposes it will do. You can add some checks for certain types in **foo** like [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0), [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0), etc:

```
else if (value is IConvertible convertible)
{
    // place here instructions like foo(IConvertible c)
    Console.WriteLine(convertible.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
      + "\thas been handled");
}
else if (value is IFormattable formattable)
{
    // place here instructions like foo(IFormattable f)
    Console.WriteLine(formattable.Format(null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
      + "\thas been handled");
}
```

Comment: You can try but you really really really should not unless you are really really need too.

Comment: What was the question, so is the answer. Whether it is needed or not is another matter.

Comment: Even if we will ignore performance and compile time "safety" issues, this is still not a good answer - it does not show how to call `foo`, it does not handle possible type mismatches and number of  arguments. And you should not operate on `type.IsPrimitive` but match incoming types with `foo` types based on position with, for example `Type.IsAssignableFrom` or `Type.IsAssignableTo`.